# Getting Error - "ArgumentError: HTTP request path is empty" during Installation

Tags: browser-automation

I am getting the below error (attached is the snapshot), while implementing Watir for Windows.

I tried to put HTTP_PrOXY in path as well as CMD console, but still it's showing the same error.

I am following the below link for implementation - 
https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/manuscript/installation/windows.md
[image]

Could you please help me to know what is required?